# Query working on local backend but not on deployed backend

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

```
 class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Quote>> {
    private static QuoteEndpoint myApiService = null;
    private Context context;

    EndpointsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Quote> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) { // Only do this once
            /*QuoteEndpoint.Builder builder = new QuoteEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });*/
            // end options for devappserver
            QuoteEndpoint.Builder builder = new QuoteEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("https://momcares-987.appspot.com/_ah/api/");

            myApiService = builder.build();
        }

        try {
            return myApiService.listQuote().execute().getItems();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Quote> result) {
        for (Quote q : result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, q.getWho() + " : " + q.getWhom(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The above class has been included in my MainActivity.java file.

http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/

I have been following this tutorial. I manually inserted quotes (Quote is the bean I am using) in the API Explorer and I successfully get the list of quotes in my emulator when I run the local server and test. However, when I deploy the same backend and run the application, I get a NullPointerException in the onPostExecuteMethod. Please help. Thanks!

Error Log:

```
06-26 11:50:19.889  26342-26342/com.sickstudios.sickapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430d4140)
06-26 11:50:19.909  26342-26342/com.sickstudios.sickapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sickstudios.sickapplication, PID: 26342
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sickstudios.sickapplication.EndpointsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:64)
            at com.sickstudios.sickapplication.EndpointsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 11:50:23.639  26342-26342/com.sickstudios.sickapplication I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26342 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.momcares-987.appspot.com/_ah/api/

Sometimes https calls raise the connectivity issue.